# Why I can't rm docker image?

Tags: docker

- I run container A from image A
- Then, I do change something in container A and commit this container to image B
- I run container B from image B and `rm -f` container A
- I want `rmi` image A but it not work.Docker said container B is using it.

So my question is,I run container B from image B but why docker say the container B is using image A when I want `rmi` image A.

My docker version:

```
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Comment: More info would be helpful here. `sudo docker version`, error message, for instance. Is there any other container (stopped or running) in the environment that is using image A? `sudo docker ps -a` would list even the stopped containers.

Comment: @Dharmit The error message show me the container ID(`cannot delete 9cad8c014bfc because the running container 72f8a5c12038 is using it`).So I can sure no other container is using image A.

Comment: What docker version are you using? Can you add output of `sudo docker version` to the question? That would help others trying to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your **image B is based on image A**. It [inherits all the image layers](https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/#how-does-a-docker-image-work) used in image A. And it adds the new image layer that you created by committing your new image B.

So image A remains always in your image layer revision tree as a dependency when you use image B. As long as you have a running container using image B you cannot delete image A.

Comment: I had the same explanation but I gave it a try on my local system. In this scenario docker would just untag the original image *A*. Then when you try to remove it using `rmi`, it will say the image doesn't exist. Assuming this is done with image name and not with the id.

Comment: I try to push image B to my private repository.And I pull image B in other VM.I run container C from image B ,it can run fine.So container C can run without image A,why in first vm container B need image A?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the intended behavior. You have effectively created a Layer(Image) B on top of Layer(Image) A.

Where Layer B is the delta of the operations on Layer A. This is based on the [Union File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) and is described in the context of docker at: [Understanding Docker](https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/)

I would say that you are now running container B, which is depending on ImageA (Providing the error). However the root issue is that Image B depends on ImageA.